# When is dynamic linking between a program and a shared library performed?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

In C, when is dynamic linking between a program and a shared library performed:

- Once loading of the program into the memory, but before executing the `main()` of the program, or
- After executing the `main()` of the program, when the first call to a routine from the library is executed? Will dynamic linking happen again when a second or third or... call to a routine from the library is executed?

I was thinking the first, until I read the following quote, and now I am not sure.

Not sure if OS matters, I am using Linux.

From Operating System Concepts:

> With dynamic linking, a stub is included in the image for each
>   library- routine reference. The stub is a small piece of code that
>   indicates how to locate the appropriate memory-resident library
>   routine or how to load the library if the routine is not already
>   present.
>
> **When the stub is executed**, it checks to see whether the needed routine is already in memory. If it is not, the program loads the
>   routine into memory. Either way, the stub replaces itself with the
>   address of the routine and executes the routine. Thus, **the next time
>   that particular code segment is reached**, the library routine is
>   executed directly, incurring no cost for dynamic linking. Under this
>   scheme, all processes that use a language library execute only one
>   copy of the library code.

Comment: In Linux, just before `main()`. ELF files (both binaries and libraries) can mark functions "constructors" or "destructors", which are run before `main()` and after the last thread exits, respectively. I *believe* the constructors are run after all libraries have been mapped, in increasing order of their priorities (101 to 65535, inclusive), but I am not certain of the order. (I do know they are all run before `main()` starts, though.) But then, there is [`dlsym()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) et al, that can also do dynamic linking at any time.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking the first, until I read the following quote, and now I am not sure.

It's complicated (and depends on exactly what you call "dynamic linking").

The Linux kernel loads `a.out` into memory. It then examines `PT_INTERP` segment (if any).

If that segment is not present, the binary is statically linked and the kernel transfers control to the `Elf{32,64}Ehdr.e_entry` (usually the `_start` routine).

If the `PT_INTERP` segment *is* present, the kernel loads it into memory, and transfers control to *it's* `.e_entry`. It is here that the dynamic linking *begins*.

The dynamic loader relocates itself, then looks in `a.out`s `PT_DYNAMIC` segment for instructions on what else is necessary.

For example, it will usually find one or more `DT_NEEDED` entries -- shared libraries that `a.out` was directly linked against. The loader loads any such libraries, initializes *them*, and resolves any *data* references between them.

IF `a.out`s `PT_DYNAMIC` has a `DT_FLAGS` entry, and IF that entry contains `DF_BIND_NOW` flag, then *function* references from `a.out` will also be resolved. Otherwise (and assuming that `LD_BIND_NOW` is not set in the environment), lazy `PLT` resolution will be performed (resolving functions as part of first call to any given function). Details [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/).

> When the stub is executed, it checks to see whether the needed routine is already in memory. If it is not, the program loads the routine into memory.

I don't know which book you are quoting from, but no current UNIX OS works that way.

Answer (score 1):

The OS (and compiler, *etc.*) certainly matters: the language itself has nothing to say about dynamic libraries (and [very little](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases#Phase_8) about linking in general).  Even if we know that dynamic linking is occurring, a strictly-conforming program cannot observe any effect from timing among its translation units (since non-local initialization [cannot have side effects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization#Notes)).

That said, the common toolchains on Linux do support [automatic initialization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bdestructor_007d-function-attribute-2420) upon loading a dynamic library (for implementing C++, among other things).  Executables and the dynamic libraries on which they depend (usually specified with `-l`) are [loaded and initialized recursively](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf#page=12) to allow initialization in each module to (successfully) use functions from its dependencies.  (There is an [unfortunate choice](https://www.sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14379) of order in some cases.)  Of course, [`dlopen(3)`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) can be used to load and initialize more libraries later.